# Convert Program to use Secure Socket Connection via java-websockets library

Tags: java, java-websocket

I am attempting to convert an existing application that uses the org.java-websocket library to allow the webserver to communicate using https instead of the previous http. After researching, the only example I was able to find is here:

https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/example/SSLServerExample.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
ChatServer chatserver = new ChatServer(
    8887); // Firefox does allow multible ssl connection only via port 443 //tested on FF16

// load up the key store
String STORETYPE = "JKS";
String KEYSTORE = Paths.get("src", "test", "java", "org", "java_websocket", "keystore.jks")
    .toString();
String STOREPASSWORD = "storepassword";
String KEYPASSWORD = "keypassword";

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(STORETYPE);
File kf = new File(KEYSTORE);
ks.load(new FileInputStream(kf), STOREPASSWORD.toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, KEYPASSWORD.toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
tmf.init(ks);

SSLContext sslContext = null;
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

chatserver.setWebSocketFactory(new DefaultSSLWebSocketServerFactory(sslContext));

chatserver.start();

}
```

The only problem with this is that I'm hesitant because it seems to be wanting you to access the keystore.jks and provide to the store password + keypassword and also seems to expect the KeyStore file to be on the running computer (or somewhere released with the software). Isn't this a security risk?

I already have the jar signed with the keystore, perhaps there is nothing more that I need to do? Can someone point me to a different example if this is not the way to do this?

This keystore I'm using is the one provided to us by an external company to our company to sign our java applications. Perhaps this is not the keystore I should be using and need to make one for this single app independently of that one?